# is it possible to use Take in LINQ when the query returns an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I'm trying to get the n-th element out of a list of anonymous types returned by a LINQ query where n is a random number from 0 to 100. Messed around with it a while now and I'm not getting anywhere. My code (with names changed to protect IP):

```
var query = from Table1 t1 in theContext.Table1 
   join Table2 t2 in theContext.Table2
    on ... 
    where ... 
   select new 
   {
       partNum = t1.part_number, 
       partSource = t2.part_source
   }

int num = new Random().Next(0, 100); 

// here's where the code I've tried fails
```

Can I somehow do a `Take<T>(100).ToList<T>()[num]` to get a single anonymous type with partNum and partSource? I ended up solving this by explicitly defining a type, but it seemed like I was missing a more elegant solution here. All I want to do is return a `Dictionary<string, string>` to the caller so I'd prefer not to have to define a type outside of this method.

**Update**: ElementAt doesn't work for this. I tried adding:

```
// get a random part from the parts list
int num = new Random().Next(0, query.Count() - 1 );
var nthElement = query.ElementAt(num);
```

And I got an exception: `The query operator 'ElementAt' is not supported.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
var item = query.Take(100).ToList()[num];
```

Of course, it would be more efficient to do:

```
var item = query.Skip(num).First();
```

Comment: Am I missing something here? Doesn't he really just want to use the ElementAt function?

Comment: (responded on other reply, for visibility)

Comment: ElementAt returns: "ElementAt is not supported ...  System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc) "

Comment: Oh lol, in that case Marc's solution may be the one to go with - does that work fine for you?

Comment: My confusion here was that all the intellisense for linq methods like Skip and Take seem to want a type in the <> but it seems that it's optional.

Comment: @jcollum: It's inferred - that's what of the nice things C# does for you. Anonymous types would be fairly useless without that feature, in fact.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you just want the [`ElementAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) extension method:

```
var nthElement = query.ElementAt(num);
```

No need to mess with `Take` queries or such, and certainly not `ToList`.

Comment: re your comment on my answer; my first example (Take/ToList) was merely to show how his attempt can be fixed. There isn't much to choose between Skip(...).First() and ElementAt(...), and I've already given you +1 ;-p

Comment: @Marc: Yeah, I understood you were just correcting his use of Take/ToList. (I was replying purely to his question and not your answer, which I hadn't seen yet.) An indeed, using Skip and First is only barely an unnecessary elaboration...

Comment: Nope, I tried ElementAt and it didn't work: "The query operator ElementAt is not supported"

Comment: Keep in mind that ElementAt is still the best option for LINQ to Objects however. Haven't had any real experience with LINQ to SQL, so I had no idea it didn't work with it.